# How can I get the 15th and last day of each month?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

I'm using Ruby and Ruby on Rails 4.

I'd like get the dates for the 15th and last day of each month for the next two months.

```
start_date = Time.now
mid_month = start_date.15th.day.of.month
last_day_of_month = start.last.day.of.month
```

What's the easiest way to accomplish this using Ruby or Rails?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will work with Rails 4:

```
start_date = Date.today
  # => Wed, 06 Nov 2013
mid_month  = (start_date + 1.month).beginning_of_month + 14
  # => Sun, 15 Dec 2013
end_month  = (start_date + 1.month).end_of_month
  # => Tue, 31 Dec 2013
```

Comment: Could you add the output ?

Answer (score 2):

I think something below you are looking for :

```
require 'date'

d = Date.today
start_date = d-d.mday
p date_15 = start_date.next_day(15)
# => #<Date: 2013-11-15 ((2456612j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
p date_last = d.next_month - d.mday
# => #<Date: 2013-11-30 ((2456627j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: mday is really good, this is they way to go if yo do not want to use methods from RoR.

Comment: @hirolau Myself don't know ROR... :( Just started learning.. So tried to solve it using Ruby..

Answer (score 1):

For the NEXT two months:

```
start_date = Date.today

[1..2].each do |month_add|
  mid_month  = (start_date + month_add.month).beginning_of_month + 14
  end_month  = (start_date + month_add.month).end_of_month
  puts 'Month: #{month_add}'
  puts "Mid Month "+mid_month
  puts "End Month "+end_month
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's some more:

```
    start_date == Date.today

    beginning = start_date.beginning_of_month
    middle = beginning.advance(weeks:2)
    end = start_date.end_of_month
```

Looks more human readable.

All these methods available from ActiveSupport class extensions, so you have to include it if not using Rails

Answer (score 0):

There might be some easier way, but this comes to my mind:

```
require 'Date'

start_date   = Date.today
mid_month    = Date.new(start_date.year, start_date.month, 15)
end_of_month = Date.new(start_date.year, start_date.month+1, 1)-1
#or
end_of_month = Date.new(start_date.year, start_date.month, 1).next_month.prev_day
```